# Switching to an image with a different number of scalar components causes access violation

Tags: c++, vtk

Migrating to vtk6.1, there is one last problem in an application. It is using vtk for volume rendering. The application should be able to (on some user interaction) switch between rendering only one scalar component per voxel via transfer function, to rendering multiple. Theoretically, it should be possible for vtk to render a volume with up to 4 such channels as far as I know). After migration to vtk 6.1, there is an access violation in code doing that, which worked in vtk 5.10.1.

Here's the simplest example I could come up with that reproduces the problem (MultiChannelTest.cxx):

```
#include <vtkColorTransferFunction.h>
#include <vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkImageAppendComponents.h>
#include <vtkMetaImageReader.h>
#include <vtkOpenGLRenderer.h>
#include <vtkPiecewiseFunction.h>
#include <vtkProperty2D.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkVolumeProperty.h>

int main (int, char *[])
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> colorTransferFunction =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();
    colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(308, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    colorTransferFunction->Build();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> piecewiseFunction =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();
    piecewiseFunction->AddPoint(0, 0.0);
    piecewiseFunction->AddPoint(308, 1.0);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper> fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper>::New();
    // to disable nagging warning about thread number:
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetNumberOfThreads(1);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName("some-test-volume.mhd");
    reader->Update();
    vtkImageData* imageData = reader->GetOutput();
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInput(imageData);
#else
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInputData(imageData);
#endif
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty> volumeProperty =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty>::New();
    volumeProperty->SetColor(0, colorTransferFunction);
    volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(0, piecewiseFunction);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume> volume = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume>::New();
    volume->SetMapper(fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper);
    volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkOpenGLRenderer> renderer =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkOpenGLRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddVolume(volume);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renWin =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);

    renWin->Render(); // when I comment this line out there is no access violation

    // now add multichannel image instead:

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageAppendComponents> append =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageAppendComponents>::New();
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    append->SetInput(imageData);
    append->AddInput(imageData);
#else
    append->SetInputData(imageData);
    append->AddInputData(imageData);
#endif
    append->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> multiChannelImageData =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
    multiChannelImageData->DeepCopy(append->GetOutput());

#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInput(multiChannelImageData);
#else
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInputData(multiChannelImageData);
#endif

    volumeProperty->SetColor(1, colorTransferFunction);
    volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(1, piecewiseFunction);

    volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);

    volume->Update();
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->Update();

    renWin->Render(); // <--- The access violation happens in here

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

From my debugging sessions, I can tell that vtk fails in`vtkVolumeRayCastSpaceLeapingImageFilter`, at line 172:

```
    for ( c = 0; c < nComponents; ++c )
      {
      *(tmpPtr++) = 0xffff;  // Min Scalar  // <-- this is line 172
      *(tmpPtr++) = 0;       // Max Scalar
```

In there, it references some output image via the `tmpPtr`. The image it somehow seems to cache; and the second time `Render` is called, it still takes the one from the first render run (which now is too small, because it would actually require twice as much space as in the first run for the second component), therefore `tmpPtr` wanders over the size of the space allocated for the image and causes the access violation.

I am at a complete loss however how to tell vtk to discard this cache, and reallocate it. The whole rendering logic is quite complex and I haven't really been able yet to fully wrap my head around it. The neuralgic points seems to be `void vtkVolumeRayCastSpaceLeapingImageFilter
::AllocateOutputData(vtkImageData *output, ...` method, where it checks if the extents and number of components have changed:

```
if (extent[0] == uExtent[0] && extent[1] == uExtent[1] &&
    extent[2] == uExtent[2] && extent[3] == uExtent[3] &&
    extent[4] == uExtent[4] && extent[5] == uExtent[5] &&
    this->Cache->GetNumberOfScalarComponents() ==
                output->GetNumberOfScalarComponents())
  {
```

For some reason, `output->GetNumberOfScalarComponents()` still returns 3 (this "space leaping filter" requires 3 components per voxel per component of the original image it seems), even after changing the input image to the one with 2 scalar components (so it should actually return 6, which would make it inequal to 3 and then trigger a re-allocation).

What do I have to do to make vtk recreate this cache with the proper dimensions? I.e. what do I have to change to make `output->GetNumberOfScalarComponents()` return the correct number the second time?

Unfortunately I haven't been able yet to determine where this `output` variable is set (or forgot to be set?), that will be my next step in debugging. Could it be a vtk bug?

It's definitely a caching problem and not a general problem with multi-channel images - When, in my program above, I comment out the first call to `Render`, the whole thing works without any problems (because `output->GetNumberOfScalarComponents()` then returns 6 and therefore a bigger buffer is allocated).

For vtk6, here's the cmake file to go along with the code above:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(MultiChannelTest)

FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MultiChannelTest MultiChannelTest.cxx)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MultiChannelTest
    vtkCommonCore vtkFiltersSources vtkInteractionStyle vtkInteractionWidgets
    vtkRenderingAnnotation vtkRenderingCore vtkRenderingFreeType
    vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL )
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a direct answer as to why the above is exactly happening, but I have a workaround for the problem now:

The caching seems to take place inside the Mapper or some of its superclasses or connected classes. When recreating the mapper, the access violation doesn't occur anymore.

So, if instead of setting the `multiChannelImage` into the existing mapper, I do this:

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> multiChannelImageData =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
    multiChannelImageData->DeepCopy(append->GetOutput());
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper>::New();
    // to disable nagging warning about thread number:
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetNumberOfThreads(1);
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInput(multiChannelImageData);
#else
    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInputData(multiChannelImageData);
#endif
volumeProperty->SetColor(1, colorTransferFunction);
volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(1, piecewiseFunction);

volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);
    volume->SetMapper(fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper);

    fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->Update();

    renWin->Render();
```

Then there is no access violation anymore. Might not be an ideal solution but at least it works.

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to explain to me what scalar components means here? I am trying to volume render a 3D image and it works correctly when I set the number of scalar components to 1. It is my understanding the number of scalar components in 2 in a 3D image or am I wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - are you asking whether a 3D input image *always* has 2 components? there is no inherent connection between number of components and the dimension of the image. a "typical" 3D image has 1 component; to have more than 1 component means that you have multiple values at each position, it requires special handling for displaying

Comment: Ahh I understand now, I had made an incorrect assumption that there is a connection between the components and the dimension of the image